# Is there any way that could help me select specific data from table in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Datasync.EFCore

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-mobile-services

Am learning about data sync from API to WPF app. Got a demo from https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/tree/main/samples. But I got into a problem that all the data inside the tables are collected on the call but I need to select specific data using Id. Tried a query etc all came to nothing. Please guide me
Thank you

PatientsController.cs

```
[Route("tables/Patients")]
public class PatientsController : TableController<Patients>
{
    public PatientsController(AppDbContext context)
        : base(new EntityTableRepository<Patients>(context))
    {

    }
}
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Patients> Patients => Set<Patients>();
}
```

Comment: `context.Patients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1)` should give you a specific `Patients` object if that's what you want (assuming `Patients` has an `Id` property)

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for the reply. I already tried that method. The  EntityTableRepository<Patients>(context) parameter only accepts dbcontext objects. When I filter like that an error pops up "cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TestApp.Api.Models.Patients>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'".

Comment: Why would you want to do that conversion and where? Where and how are you trying to filter the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Patients> Patients {get;set;}
}
```

controller:

```
[Route("tables/Patients")]
public class PatientsController : TableController<Patients>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    public PatientsController(AppDbContext context)
        : base(new EntityTableRepository<Patients>(context))
    {
        _context=context;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id){
         var Patients=_context.Patients.FindAsync(id);
         return View(Patients);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.
`[HttpGet("{id}/patientlist")]public ActionResult<Patients> Index(Int64 id){ var PatientsList = _context.Patients.Where(x => x.ClinicId == id).ToList();return Ok(PatientsList);}`.
When I make it like this I got the response I expected, Thanks for the idea.

Comment: But getting into a new problem like I call https://localhost:7178/tables/Patients/0002/patientlist?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0
I get the response of patients only from that clinic. But when I call it in my WPF application
_client = new DatasyncClient("https://localhost:7178/tables/Patients/0002/patientlist?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0", options); _table = _client.GetRemoteTable<Patients>();
All the patients in the table are brought together.

Comment: Can you share your action?And check if you get the id each time in your action when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get a record by Id, you use the URL `https://mysite/tables/myTable/id` - no search required - it will go directly to the entity you want.

If you need to limit what a user can see, you will need to implement an access control provider (which is an implementation of `IAccessControlProvider`).  This provides three methods to limit what a user can see and do model updates for ensuring the write operations store the right thing.  You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/howto/server/dotnet-core#configure-access-permissions

If it's something else, you'll need to be a little more specific.  I hang out in the issues and discussions of the azure/azure-mobile-apps repo, so feel free to file a question there.